# How do I expose a python class under its containing package without importing the entire package?

Tags: python

I have the following (toy) package structure

```
root/
 - package1/
   - __init__.py
   - class_a.py
   - class_b.py
 - run.py
```

In both `class_a.py` and `class_b.py` I have a class definition that I want to expose to `run.py`. If I want to import them this way, I will have to use

```
from package1.class_a import ClassA  # works but doesn't look nice
```

I don't like that this shows the `class_a.py` module, and would rather use the import style

```
from package1 import ClassA  # what I want
```

This is also closer to what I see from larger libraries. I found a way to do this by importing the classes in the `__init__.py` file like so

```
from class_a import ClassA
from class_b import ClassB
```

This works fine if it wasn't for one downside: as soon as I import `ClassA` as I would like (see above), I also immediately 'import' `ClassB` as, as far as I know, the `__init__.py` will be run, importing `ClassB`. In my real scenario, this means I implicitly import a huge class that I use very situationally (which itself imports tensorflow), so I really want to avoid this somehow. Is there a way to create the nice looking imports without automatically importing everything in the package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible but require a rather low level customization: you will have to customize the class of your package (possible since Python 3.5). That way, you can declare a `__getattr__` member that will be called when you ask for a missing attribute. At that moment, you know that you have to import the relevant module and extract the correct attribute.

The **init**.py file should contain (names can of course be changed):

```
import importlib
import sys
import types

class SpecialModule(types.ModuleType):
    """ Customization of a module that is able to dynamically loads submodules.
    
    It is expected to be a plain package (and to be declared in the __init__.py)
    The special attribute is a dictionary attribute name -> relative module name.
    The first time a name is requested, the corresponding module is loaded, and 
    the attribute is binded into the package
    """

    special = {'ClassA': '.class_a', 'ClassB': '.class_b'}

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        if name in self.special:
            m = importlib.import_module(self.special[name], __name__) # import submodule
            o = getattr(m, name)                      # find the required member
            setattr(sys.modules[__name__], name, o)   # bind it into the package
            return o
        else:
            raise AttributeError(f'module {__name__} has no attribute {name}')

sys.modules[__name__].__class__ = SpecialModule       # customize the class of the package
```

You can now use it that way:

```
import package1

...
obj = package1.ClassA(...)       # dynamically loads class_a on first call
```

The downside is that clever IDE that look at the declared member could choke on that and pretend that you are accessing an inexistant member because `ClassA` is not *statically* declared in `package1/__init__.py`. But all will be fine at run time.

As it is a low level customization, it is up to you do know whether it is worth it...

---

Since 3.7 you could also declare a `__gettatr__(name)` function directly at the module level.

Comment: That looks exactly like the kind of thing I was looking for. I'll try it first thing tomorrow. Thanks a million!

Comment: @Robbin: beware my original code failed to raise an AttributeError for unhandled attributes.